# Solving a simple single-ended differential amplifier

Tags: mosfet, differential, homework, small-signal, single-ended

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxGBcJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**N.B. I_D=KVov^2 without the 2**

I’m really confused with this excercise, my problem is to calculate  the A_v=v_out/vd and the cutting high frequency fH neglecting the parasites capacitors of the transistors (there is only **C1**) . I am confused because with the small signal circuit I can’t calculate the amplification of the differential amplifier because is asymmetrical and the source in not grounded.

I have **Vo=-R1*gm*V_gs2** and I can’t find **V_gs2**

[image: single ended differential]

Here it is my solution

[image: solution page 1]

I have tried to use sovrapposition effect and obtained that **Vgs_2= -Vd/2** but with a lot of effort obtaining a so clear result means that i'm not getting something about it.
btw in the end i obtained **A_v=-19.8 and fH=2.5MHz** but i'm not sure they are correct

[image: page2]

Comment: How did you obtain FH = 16MHz? As for the gain, the Vgs is equal to Vd/2. Also, how did you get the A = 112.5? gm1 = gm2 = ?? and gm3 = ??

Comment: gm1=gm2=4.4 10^-4
gm3= 8 10^-3
I tought there was no point ti show a mistaken calc but im going to add it as soon as possible

Comment: Hmm, why I've got a different result? \$ g_{m1} = \sqrt{2KI_D} = \sqrt{2 * 1m * 50 \mu A} = 316\mu S  \$ and \$ g_{m3} =  \sqrt{2KI_D} = \sqrt{2 * 10m * 100 \mu A} = 1.41mS \$

Comment: Why the 2 Is inside the Square root

Comment: Btw im going to sent my solution, wait fifteen minutes

Comment: What equation for ID current did you get from your teacher?  1 - \$I_D = K(V_{GS} - V_T)^2\$ or this one 2 - \$I_D = \frac{K}{2}(V_{GS} - V_T)^2\$

Comment: The 1 - gm=2kVov

Comment: Also notice that M1 and M2 are N channel MOSFET's not a bipolar transistor (NPN). And M3 is a P channel MOSFET, not a PNP bipolar transistor.

Comment: Yes correct, you dont know how many Times i wrote Collector instead of drain and viceversa

Comment: Maybe this will also interest you: 1 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/295771/i-o-resistance-of-common-source-mosfet-with-source-degeneration/295966#295966  2... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300044/find-the-gain-in-mosfet/300073#300073   3...https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/394295/small-signal-equivalent-circuit-mosfet/394365#394365

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful, i m preparing for an exam and After a lot of excercises i'm starting to confuse things, i m gonna take a day of Just Reading excercises already solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the equation for a drain current in the saturation region (active region) looks like this:

$$I_D = K(V_{GS} - V_T)^2$$

Then the MOSFET transconductance is equal to:

$$g_m = \frac{dI_d}{dV_{GS}} = 2K(V_{GS} - V_T)$$

But if we substitute \$(V_{GS} - V_T) = \sqrt{\frac{I_D}{K}}\$ we will end with:

$$g_m = 2K\sqrt{\frac{I_D}{K}} = 2\sqrt{KI_D}$$

Now we can calculate the transconductance for your amplifier.

\$g_{m1} = g_{m2} =2\sqrt{1\text{m} [\frac{A}{V^2}]\times 50\mu A} = 447.2 \mu S \$

\$g_{m3} =2\sqrt{10\text{m} [\frac{A}{V^2}]\times 1.6\text{mA}} = 8 \text{mS}\$

Now the voltage gain. The \$M_3\$ voltage gain is:

$$A_{V3} = -g_{m3}R_2 = 8\text{mS} \times 1.25\text{k}\Omega = -10 V/V $$

And the voltage gain of a single-ended differential amplifier we can obtain using this small-signal equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDKsGd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$V_O = -I_D * R_D = -g_{m2}*v_{gs2}*R_d$$

For this circuit \$v_{gs2} = -\frac{V_D}{2}\$ why?

Notice that becouse \$1/g_{m1} = 1/g_{m_2}\$ we have a voltage divider therefore.

KVL \$V_D = v_{gs1} + v_{sg2}\$  and notice that , \$v_{sg2} = - v_{gs2} \$)

$$\frac{V_O}{V_D} = \frac{g_{m2}*R_D}{2} = \frac{447.2\mu S * 18\text{k}\Omega}{2} = 4 V/V$$

So, the overall voltage gain is \$-10 * 4 = -40 V/V\$

As for the capacitor effect on the circuit, we need to find the pole frequency. and because \$M_3\$ is working as a common source amplifier we have this equivalent circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2facHDh.png)</sup>

We can see that because the drain of a MOSFET in the saturation region has a property of a current source we see that the pole frequency is

$$F_H = \frac{1}{2\pi RC} \approx\frac{0.16}{R_DC_D}\approx\frac{0.16}{1.25\text{k}\Omega * 100\text{pF}} = 1.28\text{MHz}$$

Comment: But ID3 Is not 100uA isnt ? And i didnt get why in this circuit vgs=Vd/2 i cant see it

Comment: I update my answer. Do you see is why vgs=Vd/2 is true?

Comment: i tought that the current generator cant able me to use the voltage divider formula

Comment: Ok now its clear thank you!

Comment: Because we want to find the resistance seen by the capacitor (equivalent resistance seen from capacitor terminal), so we turn-off all the independent voltage sources just like we do when we want to find Thevenin's equivalent resistance Rth (short all independent voltage source and open all independent current sources)

Comment: All clear Sorry It just clicked

Comment: Sorry last comment i swear, your calcs implies that vgs1 is equal to -vgs2 that where come from?

Comment: @SergioPiccione notice how I mark the voltage polarity Vd and Vgs1 and Vsg2.